# c, strtoul() returning invalid value in case of error/overflow

Tags: c, strtoull

for example:

```
int main()
{
    errno = 0;
    printf("val = %lu err: %d\n", strtoul("12345678901234", NULL, 10), errno);
}
```

output:

val = 1942892530 err: 0

Manual page says that strtoul() should return ULONG_MAX (4294967295UL) for overflown values, can somebody explain the reason strtoul() does not return ULONG_MAX in this case?

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: Note both 12345678901234 and 1942892530 have the same lower 32 bits: `73CE2FF2`.  Likely post does not reflect true code or `include`s missing or faulty `strtoul()`.

Comment: Hmm why is post tagged `strtoull` when `strtoull` is not used here?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <errno.h>` are also required

Comment: Please post a correct program, along with your compiler version and how you are invoking it

Comment: and that’s why you don’t ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a system where `unsigned long` uses 64 bits, and int uses only 32, and if you failed to include `stdlib.h` the compiler will assume that `strtoul` is a function returning an `int` value.

In that case `strtoul("12345678901234", NULL, 10)` will return `12345678901234L` or in hexadecimal `0xb3a73ce2ff2`. As the function is assumed to return an int it is converted to a 32 bits int. This kind of conversion is implementation defined, and common implementation just keep the 32 low order bits which would give here `0x73ce2ff2` or in decimal `1942892530`. You pass a 32 bits int where a 64 bits one is expected, so the result is undefined, but common implementation just use the next value in stack to complete the value. As I assumed that your implementation is little endian, and that next value is 0, because `errno` was set to 0 on previous line, and order of evaluation of parameters is undefined, so you still obtain  `1942892530` as an unsigned long. And the next value in stack happens to be a 0 too.

TL/DR: as you did not include `stdlib.h` and ignored the compiler warnings, the compiler assumed that `strtoul` should return `int`. In addition, the order of evaluation of parameters of a function is explicitely unspecified by standard. From there on, you invoke undefined behaviour and everything could have been printed.

What you should have learned from that:

- do not ignore compiler warnings
- do not forget to include headers for all functions of the standard library that you use

Comment: yes, copied and pasted the headers and missed stdlib, too bad there is no strtoui, strtoi though, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The value of `errno` is likely read *before* `strtoul` gets called.

The order of argument evaluation is [unspecified](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order):

> Order of evaluation of the operands of any C operator, including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression, and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression is unspecified (except where noted below). The compiler will evaluate them in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.
> ....

And the standard has the following example:

> In the function call
>
> ```
> (*pf[f1()]) (f2(), f3() + f4())
> ```
>
> the functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4` may be called in any order. All side effects have to be completed before the function pointed to by `pf[f1()]` is called.

Comment: But what about the return value of `strtoul`?

Comment: It is supposed to be `ULONG_MAX` in such case. The given output value looks strange indeed.